# Cannot install @angular/flex-layout in Angular cli 13.0.3

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-flex-layout

I have tried installing angular flex layout but it keeps throwing this error. Can someone please help me resolve this error

```
> (base) rajkirito@rajkirito-Vostro-15-3568:~/Web development/Angular/conFusion$ npm install @angular/flex-layout --save
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: con-fusion@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/cdk@13.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm ERR!   @angular/cdk@"^13.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/cdk@"^12.0.0" from @angular/flex-layout@12.0.0-beta.35
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/flex-layout
npm ERR!   @angular/flex-layout@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/rajkirito/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/rajkirito/.npm/_logs/2021-11-24T04_18_03_524Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

At this time you need `--force` option to use it with Angular 13.

For detail see [here](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/1368).

Answer (score 0):

There is currently (since 11/29/2021) a version for Angular 13:  [@angular/flex-layout](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/flex-layout)